# Toggling multiple jQuery icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I'm having a few problems with my icon toggling in jQuery.

The html for each toggled section is:

```
<h2 class="collapse"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 1.1</h2>
<p>Hidden text.</p>
```

And the javaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".collapse").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        $("span").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
    }).next().hide();
});
```

JSfiddle also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LADransfield/gy653bpL/14/).

When I click any of the collapsible sections, all of the icons change at once, though not all of them expand/collapse.

I also can't get my icon to be on the same line as the text, though that's a smaller problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go : http://jsfiddle.net/gy653bpL/15/.

add some CSS :

```
.collapse span {display:inline-block;}
```

toogle only the active span :

```
$(this).find("span").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting all span elements.you need to only target the child span element of clicked h2 element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$(".collapse").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
}).next().hide();
});
```

and for aligning the icon set style `float` to `left`:

```
 .ui-icon-triangle-1-e{float:left;}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztg2c1vn/)**